# what does "a female attendant to a lady of rank" mean?

Tags: meaning

I checked a [dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-cobuild-learners/to) that said this about the "to":

> *To* can be used as a way of introducing the person or organization you are employed by, when you perform some service for them.

but what is the meaning of "a lady of rank"?

Comment: If you looked up *to*, why didn't you also look up the word [**rank**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rank?s=t)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*A female attendant to a lady of rank* can include someone like a maid, also called lady's maid in some circles, who works for a lady of higher standing in society. For example, **a maid to a baroness**.

Comment: +1 for answering the title and the question within the body.

Comment: hi thx for your answer,But I got anther question from your answer.
"lady's maid in some circles" what dose the "circles" mean here.
dose "in some circles" means "in some condition" or "in some group of people"?

Comment: Circles as in social circles. Certain sections of society. Based on money and position

Answer (score 0):

*A lady of rank* is a lady with a formal title such as baroness or dame.

Comment: Or  more informally, a woman of the upper class.